# Значение выражения "улыбаясь затылком"

Tags: фразеология

Услышал по телевизору фразу, которая заставила меня вспомнить это выражение.
Мне оно, вроде, знакомо. К своему удивлению обнаружил, что в Сети примеры можно по пальцам пересчитать - не очень прозрачные по смыслу.

Вопрос.

Слышали ли вы его раньше и как понимаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, конечно, фразеологизм, но такую улыбку можно попробовать изобразить, и тогда можно понять, что означает фраза. Однажды на занятии по психологии нам, молодым студентам , дали такое задание, потом долго смеялись. У всех были глупые лица, бессмысленные, ушедшие в себя. Когда человек задумывается о чём-то своём, сокровенном, у него во взгляде появляется такая ласка, нежность, он весь уходит в улыбку, но не широкую, а вот именно глубокую, отрешённую от всего на свете, он весь тепло и нега, весь улыбка, которая как бы отражается зеркально на затылке.

Получается, что "улыбаясь затылком" - это улыбаясь отрешённо и чувственно, вкладывая в улыбку всего себя. Мне так видится.

Comment: Т.е. ничего ехидного, никакого злорадства или камня за пазухой?!

Comment: Смотря о чём задумаешься. Может, я как раз и представила, как мой враг"прогорел" и вся в этой мысли, и блаженная улыбка от сознания , что он наказан. Не была в таком состоянии, не знаю, но вполне возможно. Мне кажется, как нормальные улыбки бывают разные, так и "затылком". Главное, чтобы не глазами и губами (искренняя), а отрешённая, чувства на лице не отражаются,они в глубине тебя, а улыбка как бы приклеенная к голому затылку.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение знакомо. Я его понимаю так: и со спины можно понять, что человек улыбается или насмехается. Как-то так, хоть и примитивно.))

Comment: Это понятно. Хотелось бы чуть конкретнее.  Тут тонкость в том, что не ясно цель и обстоятельства такой улыбки. Улыбающийся злорадствует и сознательно прячет от публики этакий камень за пазухой или тут подобная ассоциация неправильна (необязательна)?

Answer (score 0):

Затылком, наверное, улыбаются по-разному.

http://www.stihi.ru/2012/01/30/964

Мне казалось,  сумела быть значимой, важною…
Ты с азартом следил, сам себе режиссер.
Улыбаясь затылком  ухмылкой бумажною,
Дал понять, что я чей-то дублер.

Comment: Спасибо, я видел эти стихи. Но уж очень неоднозначно...